# unix - compare columns of two files

Tags: awk

I have two files. First file is masterlist of IDS. Second file is normal input file.

I'm trying to print only the records of input where it's id (column 3) is NOT in masterlist (column 1).

sample:

masterlist.txt

```
111
222
333
```

input.txt

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,abc,111,xyz,xyz,xyz
abc,abc,222,xyz,xyz,xyz
abc,abc,333,xyz,xyz,xyz
abc,abc,444,xyz,xyz,xyz
```

desired output:

```
col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,abc,444,xyz,xyz,xyz
```

I have come up with this code so far but I'm not getting the correct output.

```
awk -F\| '!b{a[$0]; next}$3 in a {true; next} {print $3","$4","$11","$12}' masterlist.txt b=1 input.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let us know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($3 in a)' masterlist.txt  FS="," input.txt
```

Comment: @user2058738, it worked fine for me, can you check once if your file is having control M characters? by doing `cat -v Input_file` do it for both the files and let me know then if they are there.

Comment: hi ravi. if masterlist is blank it does not ouput any record. ideally it should print all the record of input file if masterlist is blank.

Comment: @user2058738, if any file is empty with ZERO lines `awk` will NOT be reading it simple.

Comment: The problem is that when the masterlist.txt file is empty, `FNR==NR` is true for the _second_ file.  That's why nothing gets printed in that case.